# I just want that my should be highlighted on the form after selecting it the radio button

Tags: javascript, html, xml

this is my html code please have a look.
and the below is my js code please help me with highlighting the data.
in this code i reading the data from the xml file and then printing it on the web page using js and then i want to get the selected data by user to be highlited on the form.

in the xml file whole the infromation of the customer has given.

````
Html Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Client Rental</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="classdemo_2.css">
<script type="text/javascript"enter code here src="jsonfilehandler.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <header><h1>Client Rental Information</h1> <img src="1.png">
</header>

<h2>Search the Client Below</h2>

<table>
    <tr><td>Search By Last Name</td><td></td><td></td><td><input type="text" size="30" id="lastname"></td></tr> 
</table>
<br>
<h3 id="searchvalue"></h3>
<br>
<table id="searchresults" ></table>

<form id="register" onsubmit="register();return false">
<table class="form">
    <tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" id="lastname" size="15" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,15}" required="true"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" id="firstname" size="15" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,15}" required="true"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address</td><td><input type="text" id="address" size="25" required="true"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sate_province</td><td><input type="text" id="state" placeholder="state" size="15" required="true"></td></tr>

    <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="email" id="email" placeholder="example@example.com" size="20" required="true"></td></tr>


    <tr><td>Phone Number</td><td><input type="phone" id="phone" placeholder="A1A1A1" size="15" required="true"></td></tr>

</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



    <footer class="footer">
        Contact information

    </footer>

</table>

</body>
</html>



Js Code:-
/*jsonfilehandler.js*/
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var r;
var index;
window.onload=loaddata;
function loaddata() {
    //event listener
    document.getElementById("lastname").addEventListener("keyup", function (){ searchFullName(this.value);},false);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
     r = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      //displayData(r);
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", "rentalclients.json", true);
  xhr.send();




}

function searchFullName(name) {

    //var r=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    var output=" ";
    var searchname;
    var displayRadiobuttons= "";
    for(var i=0; i<r.length; i++)
    {
        var obj=r[i];
        searchname=obj.last_name;
        if(searchname.toLowerCase().startsWith(name))
        {   

                    obj=obj.last_name+"\t\t\t\t"+obj.first_name;
                    displayRadiobuttons+="<input type=radio name=listitem";
                    displayRadiobuttons += " value=" + i + " ";
                    displayRadiobuttons+= "onclick=if(this.checked) {setClientObject(searchname)}>";

                    displayRadiobuttons+=obj+ "<br>";



            }
    }

document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML=displayRadiobuttons;
//displayRadiobuttons=  onclick=if(this.checked){setClientObject()};

}




function setClientObject(myname) {

var c=0;
alert(c);

 index=i;
 var dataitem;
  var clientobject = {
    lastname,
    firstname,
    address,
    postalcode,
    state,
    email,
    phone
  };

var searchname;

  for(var i=0; i<r.length; i++)
    {
        var obj=r[i];
        searchname=obj.last_name;
        if(searchname.toLowerCase().startsWith(name))
        {   

  clientobject.lastname = document.getElementByTagName("last_name").value;
  clientobject.firstname = document.getElementByTagName("first_name").value;
  clientobject.address = document.getElementByTagName("address").value;
  clientobject.postalcode = document.getElementByTagName("state_prov").value;

  clientobject.email = document.getElementByTagName("email").value;
  clientobject.phone = document.getElementByTagName("phone").value;

        }           
    }
  //input variables into clientobject


    document.getElementById("lastname").value = clientobject.lastname;
  document.getElementById("firstname").value = clientobject.firstname;
  document.getElementById("address").value = clientobject.address;
  document.getElementById("state").value = clientobject.state;


        document.getElementById("email").value = clientobject.phone;
  document.getElementById("phone").value = clientobject.state;



  }```
````

Comment: Not enough information and please use code snippet to attach the code

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To get a good answer it will help to edit your question. Be specific about what is being asked and only include the html and code needed to reproduce the issue you are having. How have you tried to highlight the text you want highlighted? See how to create a minimal, verifiable, complete working example for more information on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted the code, but I still don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Client Rental</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="classdemo_2.css">
<script type="text/javascript"enter code here src="jsonfilehandler.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <header><h1>Client Rental Information</h1> <img src="1.png">
</header>

<h2>Search the Client Below</h2>

<table>
    <tr><td>Search By Last Name</td><td></td><td></td><td><input type="text" size="30" id="lastname"></td></tr> 
</table>
<br>
<h3 id="searchvalue"></h3>
<br>
<table id="searchresults" ></table>

<form id="register" onsubmit="register();return false">
<table class="form">
    <tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" id="lastname" size="15" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,15}" required="true"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" id="firstname" size="15" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,15}" required="true"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address</td><td><input type="text" id="address" size="25" required="true"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sate_province</td><td><input type="text" id="state" placeholder="state" size="15" required="true"></td></tr>

    <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="email" id="email" placeholder="example@example.com" size="20" required="true"></td></tr>


    <tr><td>Phone Number</td><td><input type="phone" id="phone" placeholder="A1A1A1" size="15" required="true"></td></tr>

</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



    <footer class="footer">
        Contact information

    </footer>

</table>

</body>




<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var r;
var index;
window.onload=loaddata;
function loaddata() {
    //event listener
    document.getElementById("lastname").addEventListener("keyup", function (){ searchFullName(this.value);},false);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
     r = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      //displayData(r);
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", "rentalclients.json", true);
  xhr.send();




}

function searchFullName(name) {

    //var r=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    var output=" ";
    var searchname;
    var displayRadiobuttons= "";
    for(var i=0; i<r.length; i++)
    {
        var obj=r[i];
        searchname=obj.last_name;
        if(searchname.toLowerCase().startsWith(name))
        {   

                    obj=obj.last_name+"\t\t\t\t"+obj.first_name;
                    displayRadiobuttons+="<input type=radio name=listitem";
                    displayRadiobuttons += " value=" + i + " ";
                    displayRadiobuttons+= "onclick=if(this.checked) {setClientObject(searchname)}>";

                    displayRadiobuttons+=obj+ "<br>";



            }
    }

document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML=displayRadiobuttons;
//displayRadiobuttons=  onclick=if(this.checked){setClientObject()};

}




function setClientObject(myname) {

var c=0;
alert(c);

 index=i;
 var dataitem;
  var clientobject = {
    lastname,
    firstname,
    address,
    postalcode,
    state,
    email,
    phone
  };

var searchname;

  for(var i=0; i<r.length; i++)
    {
        var obj=r[i];
        searchname=obj.last_name;
        if(searchname.toLowerCase().startsWith(name))
        {   

  clientobject.lastname = document.getElementByTagName("last_name").value;
  clientobject.firstname = document.getElementByTagName("first_name").value;
  clientobject.address = document.getElementByTagName("address").value;
  clientobject.postalcode = document.getElementByTagName("state_prov").value;

  clientobject.email = document.getElementByTagName("email").value;
  clientobject.phone = document.getElementByTagName("phone").value;

        }           
    }
  //input variables into clientobject


    document.getElementById("lastname").value = clientobject.lastname;
  document.getElementById("firstname").value = clientobject.firstname;
  document.getElementById("address").value = clientobject.address;
  document.getElementById("state").value = clientobject.state;


        document.getElementById("email").value = clientobject.phone;
  document.getElementById("phone").value = clientobject.state;



  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i want to that the searched data should be highlighted on the form after selecting the radio button.

Comment: its created in the javascript, just run it if possible.